# openerp payroll (using previous payslips data)

Tags: odoo

I want to calculate Holiday payment using OpenERP payroll. I managed to successfully configure Salaries calculations depending on my needs, but I'm stuck at using previous payslips data into new one).

What I want to do is calculate Holidays payments, which requires to use previous three months gross (or bruto) salary and worked days (at those three months) and get average $/day for these three months. Then I could use this parameter to calculate how much money employee should get money for his holidays.

I just don't find a way to use such data, because all data is being used at present payslip (like rules, categories, inputs).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Salary Rules using python expression have available a `payslip` object.
This object has `sum` method:

```
def sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None)
```

Probably you can write a rule containing something like:

```
payslip.sum('GROSS', a_start_date, a_end_date)
```

You'll need to add expression to calculate your star and end dates, but I'm not sure if you the `datetime` and `timedelta` objects are available in the evaluated expression...

Comment: So that method would only get gross from exact date I written? For example 2012-06-01? Or it could be possible to make it get date for example previous one from the current being calculated (like calculating for July, and get the date that is previous, so it would be June?
Because without that it would be quite limited.
If it would be possible to use as object than such formula could be used for every salary, not needing to change dates manually.

Comment: I tried this, but it always returns zero. Maybe it can't read something from the code (it happens sometimes when code itself is good, but values given are not recognized).
I tried to so set from_date - '2012-06-01', to_date - none, but it returned 0, even though GROSS values are not zero. Maybe I need something to do with self value or is it always takes it as it is for the user that has thas rule in his asigned salary structure?

Answer (score 0):

Great to hear that you have right configuration of the Payroll, as the Payroll Engine is quite a strong and technical, but regarding  your holiday payment it is purely a customization the generic implementation does not come with the any special feature like this,

But If you want o make it part of the salary slip yes you can always some complex Head with Python Code which can calculate your requirement. you have variable like :

```
# employee: hr.employee object
# rules: object containing the rules code (previously computed)
**# worked_days: object containing the computed worked days.**
# inputs: object containing the computed inputs.
```

Hope this will help thanks